# Cannot insert blob into SQLite database

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite

I have a problem with blob sql datatype, the problem is that I cannot insert the NSData to database, the compiler shows no errors, but the database file size hasn't change after data  insertion,i've tried all kind of things, this is my last function i wrote but it seem to work neider, please help, thanks in advance!

```
sqlite3 *database;
        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)== SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSString *statement = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into %@(date,name,type,urlpath) values('%@','%@','0','%@')",mainPath,
                                   currentTime,
                                   (*incomingObject).fileName, 
                                   filterURL];
            NSLog(@"\n--==%@ %@==--",(*incomingObject).fileName,(*incomingObject).urlAdress);
            const char *sqlStatement = [statement UTF8String];
            [statement release];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);
            sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
            sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        break;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not really good idea to pass parameters values in SQL statement. In this way you not protected from SQL injection.

I suggest to you use SQLite C-API functions like: **sqlite3_bind_***. You will find `sqlite3_bind_blob` method which will allow you to insert blob into table

Comment: sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStatement, 5, [(*incomingObject).file bytes], [(*incomingObject).file length], NULL);

Comment: Can you show code with that part in first post? Does it insert other data in that request? And which one from properties is blob data? Also you should pass _bytes_ not _NSData_ itself. For example like this: ` sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, index, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_STATIC);` Where _imageData_ is NSData object.

Comment: Also make sure what `compiledStatement` is not **NULL**. I just don't see this kind of check in your code. In case if data not inserted at all, make sure your database placed outside of application bundle which is signed itself and it's content can't be changed.

Comment: if (!compiledStatement)
  {
   printf("\n §Compiled statements is NULL");
  } // it shows that the statement isnt NULL

Comment: yes, other data is inserted in the code, but the blob just does't react !!

Comment: CREATE TABLE filemanager(id integer primary key,
date text,
name text,
type text,
icon blob,
file blob,
urlpath text);

Comment: In your question I don't see at all, where you try to add blob data into database, there is no _file_ column in your insertion SQL request.